# Meteor.js and Chrome - Mouse Wheel Issue when using transform - CSS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor, transform, mousewheel

There is a strange bug inside my App prototype using `transform:translate(...)`.
The Mouse Wheel is not working properly inside the transformed view:

---

http://foods.rk.meteor.com/

If you click the category 'Alle' you will see the searchResults inside a list.
It is not possible to scroll with the Mouse Wheel. But if you resize the browser or focus the searchInput: Everything works fine.

If you go back to the categories and resize the browser or focus the searchInput: The Mouse Wheel doesn't work anymore.

In IE11 and Firefox everything works the way I want.
In Chrome Version 41 it doesn't work

I tried to replicate the issue without meteor, but it wasn't possible for me:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emwbjZ

---

Can you confirm the issue? Do you know a workaround?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your scrollable css isn't handling it properly.

Edit your 'scrollable' class and add in the ability to scroll vertically. This doesn't happen naturally since it is not the top level div:

```
.scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Your current setting is `auto`

Comment: Thanks for the advice Akshat, but this doesn't fix the issue. I use `overflow :auto` because scrollbars should be visible only if there is something to scroll

Comment: @ReneKaesler I edited the CSS on your site in chrome web tools and it fixes the issue. Try to give the `overflow: scroll` property to the element you need scrollable. Perhaps it is being overridden.

Comment: @ReneKaesler If you run `$(".scrollable").css({'overflow':'scroll'})` in your js console on your site it fixes the issue, a quicker way to check.

Comment: @ReneKaesler Also it breaks when you move back and forth from `Alle`. because you've also made some other div scrollable. If you remove this property and only apply it to the body bit with the items then it always scrolls regardless of when you change the overscroll

Comment: Yes, because when you edit inside the CSS in web tools you resize the page(scrollbar will be added). Hardcoded it doesen't work. I tried it.

Comment: I cant apply a scrollbar to the body. The searchform is a widget. It will be included in a sidebar. :-(